# modular sinatra app doesn't log exceptions

Tags: exception, logging, sinatra

I'm creating my first app in Sinatra and I have problems with logging. I read some topics here about logging in Sinatra and thanks to them I can log requests but I cannot see error stacks in my log file - they show only in console.

Here is what I've got so far:

**app.rb**

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'bundler'
Bundler.require(:default, ENV['RACK_ENV'].to_sym)

require 'sinatra/base'
require 'sinatra/config_file'
require 'sinatra/partial'

class App < Sinatra::Base
  configure do
    enable :sessions, :logging, :partial_underscores, :dump_errors, :raise_errors

    log_file = File.new("#{settings.root}/log/#{settings.environment}.log", 'a+')
    log_file.sync = true
    use Rack::CommonLogger, log_file

    set :root, File.dirname(__FILE__)
    set :logger_level, :info
    set :logger_log_file, File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), "/log/#{environment}.log")

    helpers do
      def logger
        @logger ||= begin
          @logger = ::Logger.new(self.class.logger_log_file)
          @logger.level = ::Logger.const_get((self.class.logger_level || :warn).to_s.upcase)
          @logger.datetime_format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
          @logger
        end
      end
    end
  end

  error do
    logger.error env['sinatra.error'].message
    redirect to('500.html')
  end
end
```

And when I set

```
get '/' do
  raise 'some test error'
end
```

Stack trace shows only in console. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried it without the helper you've defined? Sinatra [already supplies a helper](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Logging).

Comment: Yeah, you are right I don't need helper for logger to work so I removed it. But it still doesn't show exceptions in my log file. Only thing that I get is `127.0.0.1 - - [03/Sep/2013 14:34:29] "GET /__sinatra__/500.png HTTP/1.1" 304 - 0.0014`

Comment: Instead of the file setup you have there (`log_file = File.new`…) how about trying the standard library's [Logger](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/logger/rdoc/Logger.html)? e.g. `logger = Logger.new("path/to/logfile"); logger.level = Logger::ERROR; use Rack::Commonlogger, logger`

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't help at all. When I switched to Logger my logs stopped working. My tests showed me: `NoMethodError: undefined method `write' for #<Logger:0x007fe4f5efd0f8>`. When I added `class ::Logger; alias_method :write, :<<; end` before your code my logs returned but I'm still getting only `127.0.0.1 - - [03/Sep/2013 19:41:51] "GET /__sinatra__/500.png HTTP/1.1" 304 - 0.0046` :(

Comment: I found [this issue](https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/issues/484) that seems to be the root of the problem. It's got suggestions for workarounds.

Comment: Awesome! I added catching STDERR to my logfile by `STDERR.reopen logfile` and my logs showed exceptions and stack traces. If you add answer to my question I will gladly mark it :)

Comment: You put it in, you did more work than me :) It got me started thinking about how to fix this mess, so my contribution will be to the main project. Glad you got it working!

Comment: Check my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20527693/316700